# Display user input value upon submit in react

Tags: reactjs

I want the user to input some text, click submit and the text will be displayed below.
I was able to get the input text as a whole, and print it in console. But I don't know how to display the text.

Here's my code:
https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-curie-ej6og?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");
  const textChangeHandler = (i) => {
    setEnteredText(i.target.value);
    //console.log(i.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    const x = enteredText;
    console.log(x);
    setEnteredText("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Get user input</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        placeholder="type something"
        type="text"
        value={enteredText}
        onChange={textChangeHandler}
      />
      <button type="submit" >
        Submit
      </button>
      </form>

      <p>You just typed: {x}</p>  // This is wrong. x is out of scope. But i'm not sure how to write this line. 
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use an additional state variable to store the "submitted text". You would update that new state variable with the text from the `enteredText` state variable before emptying it. You could also make sure the "submitted text" has a value before displaying it.

I am including code that does what I described, but you can also try implementing it on your own before looking at it:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import "./styles.css";

export default function App() {
  const [enteredText, setEnteredText] = useState("");
  const [submittedText, setSubmittedText] = useState(null);
  const textChangeHandler = (i) => {
    setEnteredText(i.target.value);
    //console.log(i.target.value);
  };

  const submitHandler = (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    setSubmittedText(enteredText);
    setEnteredText("");
  };

  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Get user input</h1>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <input
        placeholder="type something"
        type="text"
        value={enteredText}
        onChange={textChangeHandler}
      />
      <button type="submit" >
        Submit
      </button>
      </form>

      {submittedText && (<p>You just typed: {submittedText}</p>)}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: thanks for the hint!!! i got it sorted it out before looking at your answer.

Comment: one addition question: what does `{submittedText && (...)}` mean? i just wrote `<p>You just typed: {submittedText}</p>`

Comment: If submitted text has any value, `submittedText` will return true, in other words - render this part - 

(<p>You just typed: {submittedText}</p>)}

If submittedText has any value

Comment: It's meant to check that the `submittedText` is not `null` or `undefined` before displaying it, but since the initial value is `""`, then it becomes useless. I have updated my answer by initializing the `submittedText` to `null` so that it makes sense. You can learn more about "Inline If with Logical && Operator" [on the documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator).